# Unable to print specified pages in Word 2003

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, microsoft-office-2003

A user here is unable to print specified pages with Word 2003. When she press ALT-P and select "Pages", she types "1,2,4,9,10" but the whole document get printed.

A reboot has been done, Office reinstallation and Windows Update has also been performed.

Any takers?

Thanks,
David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the radio button is changing to "selected pages:" from "whole document"?

Comment: Absolutely jnk!

Comment: Just did some quick research, and it looks like it could be the file if it is the result of a letter-type merge or uses sections.  Have you tried having another user print the same document from another terminal?  If it is a letter-type merge/uses sections it will require specifying sections to print.  See http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/Formatting/PrintMultipleSections.htm

Comment: God damn! I just can't believe that you are right!

Comment: Even a broken clock is right twice a day! :)  Glad it worked.